# How to send adaptive card json to bot service api from external source?

Tags: botframework, microsoft-teams, adaptive-cards, microsoft-graph-teams

How to send adaptive card json to  Azure Bot Service api from external source?

[Added on 07/08/2020]
[image]

Trying to send adaptive card json or content to api/notify to show custom messages ms teams.

Just trying to send the adaptive card from Azure Bot Service to MS Teams via channel created.Currently i have hard coded the details/links/text in source code (Azure Bot Services app). Would like to send the customized adaptive card each time by modifying the content of adaptive card.

Currently if i call the [www.sampleAzurebotservices.com/api/notify](http://www.sampleAzurebotservices.com/api/notify) the hardcoded data is getting displayed. Hope this gives a gud picture.

Comment: When you say bot service API, do you mean the Azure Bot Service or do you mean your specific bot's endpoint? Are you trying to send an Adaptive Card to your bot (very unusual) or are you trying to have your bot send an Adaptive Card to Teams (normal)? What have you tried so far? Please edit your question to give more information.

Comment: Hey Nanda, could you give us here a litle bit more detail about what you're trying to do?

You have an adaptive card and want to send it to the bot service to send it to teams? You don't have to use the bot service, its way more convinient but you can theoretically send your cards directly to teams if you want to.

Comment: You have an adaptive card and want to send it to the bot service to send it to teams? [Nanda] :Yes 

Any reference links would be helpful...

Comment: @Nandakumar - Can you give us an example of a message you're sending to www.sampleAzurebotservices.com/api/notify and the code that handles the message? (Since there are multiple people in this thread, you will need to @ mention me if you want me to see your reply.)

Comment: @Nandakumar - Is Abhijit's answer acceptable?

Comment: @KyleDelaney, No that is not sufficient.

Comment: @Nandakumar - Are you willing to provide the information I asked for so that we can help you?

Comment: @Nandakumar - Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney - Please refer the attached screenshot.

Comment: @Nandakumar - Thank you for the image. I can see that you've put effort into explaining what you're trying to do, but that's not the information I'm asking for. I'm asking what you're currently doing. I need to see a minimal code example that results in your undesired behavior so I can see what the problem is and how to fix it. So far you haven't even told us what language your bot is written in. Please provide bot code and Adaptive Card JSON and a screenshot of the output in Teams. You may benefit from reading this Stack Overflow guide: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Nandakumar - Are you still working on this?

Comment: @KyleDelaney, Thanks for your prompt replies. I would be expecting some approaches which is feasible for one way communication MS Teams. 

Below are the things which I have tired out.

I have tried Power Automate but it has API call limitation. I was expecting some Graph API but non available for messaging to bulk of users. Also I have tried the Bot Framework with MS Teams App but after installation of App three more users the Callback/Conference Object is generated hence unable to communicate.

Comment: @Nandakumar - It now sounds like you're saying you can't figure out a way to send messages to users. In your question, it sounds like you're describing a problem where messages can be sent to the users but Adaptive Cards aren't getting rendered correctly. Is that no longer your problem? Are you no longer able to send messages to users?

Comment: @KyleDelaney, It isn't about adaptive cards. It is all about the approaches how to send one way message notification to users in MSteams.

Comment: Are you saying you just want to know how to send proactive messages? Does this help? https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/send-proactive-messages

Comment: @KyleDelaney, I appreciate your intent. But this doesn't help !! I have already went through this doc.

Comment: @Nandakumar - Do you understand that we need more information from you in order to help you? I asked if you're trying to send proactive messages and you didn't answer that question. I've asked many questions in this thread that remain unanswered. Please consider reading it over and providing the needed information.

Answer (score 0):

@Nanda, Check this [documentation](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/conversation-basics?tabs=dotnet#send-a-message) for your reference on how to send message to bot. Documentation has text message, for adaptive card you can use below code snippet.

```
var reply = MessageFactory.Attachment(new Attachment { ContentType = AdaptiveCard.ContentType, Content = adaptiveCard }); //pass adaptive card to content
var result = await turnContext.SendActivityAsync(reply, cancellationToken);
```

Let me know if you face any issue.

Comment: @KyleDelaney, Please refer the screenshot attached in the Parent question. Hope that will be useful to get the clarity what I was seeking. I know that the referred use case can be done via one way notification in MS Teams Apps. I was expecting to send it to multiple users without app with notifications on Activity and Chat. Alos I have tried out COmpany communicator app.

Comment: Please refer the screenshot attached in the Parent question. Hope that will be useful to get the clarity what I was seeking. I know that the referred use case can be done via one way notification in MS Teams Apps. I was expecting to send it to multiple users without app with notifications on Activity and Chat. Alos I have tried out COmpany communicator app.

Comment: @Nandakumar - Do you still need help?

Comment: @KyleDelaney, Yees

Comment: @Nandakumar - Well it's been so long since you've asked this question that I recommend accepting this answer and asking a new question about the issue you're currently facing.